# Cumulative sum start by zero on new year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I want to write an SQL query (SQL Server) where I can cumulate values of a column, but I want to start the cumulation again if a new year is starting.

For Example I am having a table like this:

[image]

My query is currently looking like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR ASC, Monthnum ASC) as RESULT 
from TABLE 
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTHNUM DESC
```

And my result looks like this:

[image]

But what I really want, is my result to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `partition by` year:

```
SELECT *, SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY Monthnum) as RESULT 
from TABLE               --^--> here
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTHNUM DESC
```